# Ordering event with Esper java

Tags: java, iot, esper, event-stream-processing

I'm developing IoT Platform and what i need to do is preserve the events order. 
For example, Sometimes slow network may causes the problem that previous events reached after newer events. In this case, I need to reorder the events with timestamp before excute some logics.

I think i can use Esper for my project but not sure yet.
I'm really new to Esper.

So i want to know whether Esper is suitable for my projects.
And Is there any example for ordering events with esper using java?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to reorder events in Esper that waits for late arriving events. It is called [time_order](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.2.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-time-order). You often use it together with [controlling time using the API](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.2.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#apiruntime-time).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment is really helpful.